# Complex lag inheritance with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Firstly "complex lag inheritance" may not be the clearest title, so suggestions welcome.  I have a large dataset of ordered segmented strings that I need to group by stem matching of segments.  This looping example demonstrates the required logic:

```
require(tidyverse)

x = data_frame(name = c('smith', 'smith.james', 'smith.jill', 
                        'taylor', 'taylor.ian', 'walker', 'walker.john', 'walker.john.sid',
                        'reed.snow', 'reed.snow.harry', 'reed.snow.helen.jane'), 
               family_name = NA_character_)

x$family_name[1] = x$name[1]

for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
  # if current record matches previous record's family assignment..
  family_match = str_detect(string = x$name[i], pattern = paste0('^', x$family_name[i-1], '[.]'))
  x$family_name[i] = ifelse(family_match, x$family_name[i-1], x$name[i])
}

print(x)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    name                 family_name
#>    <chr>                <chr>      
#>  1 smith                smith      
#>  2 smith.james          smith      
#>  3 smith.jill           smith      
#>  4 taylor               taylor     
#>  5 taylor.ian           taylor     
#>  6 walker               walker     
#>  7 walker.john          walker     
#>  8 walker.john.sid      walker     
#>  9 reed.snow            reed.snow  
#> 10 reed.snow.harry      reed.snow  
#> 11 reed.snow.helen.jane reed.snow
```

I have tried using this looping approach and it does not seem feasible given the data size, so the alternative is a vectored dplyr approach or python.

The heart of the problem is that each `family_name` assignment is based on match of either the current record's `name` (when inferring new family names), or the previous record's `family_name`.  I don't see how to reconcile this logic with an approach using e.g. `pmap_chr`, but if I'm wrong I'd love to know how.

Comment: I should note - an alternative strategy based more heavily on regex seems difficult when the family_name components can be an indeterminate number of segments (as defined here by . seperators) long..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses no regular expressions or explicit loops although internally `Reduce` would be using a loop.  No packages are used.

```
Names <- paste0(x$name, ".")
iter <- function(x, y) if (startsWith(y, x)) x else y
Reduce(iter, Names, acc = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
 [1] "smith."     "smith."     "smith."     "taylor."    "taylor."   
 [6] "walker."    "walker."    "walker."    "reed.snow." "reed.snow."
[11] "reed.snow."
```

Comment: This solution has knocked my question out of the stadium.